# Finding common entries in two very large database tables

Tags: java, database, algorithm, join

I have two very large tables containing millions of entries and they contain similar records. So, TableA might have different column structure than TableB to store the same data but both TableA and TableB contain a column for a unique fingerprint of the record. What is the best way to find out the common entries in TableA and TableB which contain the same fingerprint? Similar questions has been asked here a few times here but there is a change here.

Say, I store the pk of the common entries in a `TableC(pk_a, pk_b, fingerprint)`, which denote the common tuple in TableA and TableB. Now TableC needs to be updated whenever records are added to/delete from either TableA or TableB.

My solution for the first part is to take the join of TableA and TableB on fingerprint being the same and adding it to TableC.

For the second part, query TableC for the similar fingerprint and then update TableC if any matches are found. If no matches are found, scan through the TableB (say record was added to TableB) for the fingerprint and then update TableC.

But this is pretty intuitive and naïve. I feel it can be done in a better way.

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: What is the final use? I mean, the correlation is needed to be ready in real time? Or maybe you could avoid all the overhead at the insert and just run a batch process at midnight?

Comment: The final use can vary. Its an interview question. Although, running a batch process might be a very practical solution but maybe people are already doing it using some other clever mechanisms.

Comment: Well, even in an interview I would ask back in hope to get a more concise set of requeriments (wider requeriments --> less cost effective implementation). Another interesting question would have be if there are some columns in common, even if they are not PK they would have come in handy when doing joins. Anyway, I am writting an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

First I'll tell you how I see the issue:

- The fingerprint is calculated as a function of one of the keys of the table (probably the PK, could be also a candidate PK). If not, it makes no sense (*1). So the fingerprint is invariable.
- Also, each fingerprint is unique for each table(big trouble if it is not).
- Ideally, I would add the fingerprint to each of the table as a new attribute (NOT NULL UNIQUE), set by a trigger when the row is created. If the tables are not too big and the function is not too CPU intensive, you might change that for a DB function that calculates the fingerprint to be used in the selects.
- If you cannot modify the original tables, then a secondary table is needed. You can either use a only table as you proposed or one table for each of the original tables (fingerprintA, pkA / fingerprintB, pkB). Your solution may be faster, mine is simpler(only insert/delete, no updates) and more extensible (in case table C appears tomorrow). Records of this/es table/s are only modified by insert or delete actions in the original tables (ideally through triggers).
- As with every engineering, the finer points of the problem (what you expect to do with the solution and what are you able to do) tip the balance to one solution of the other.

(*1) If you can change what your record is by changing an attribute which is not part of a PK, then your model is wrong.

Comment: The fingerprint is not a calculated value, it is supplied by the data. Say a song. The name of the song can be different (due to some spelling mistake) but the song's fingerprint is same and unique to it. So, even if the name or other properties of a song S is different in TableA and TableB, the fingerprint remains the same. Also each table may contain records with similar fingerprint but lets just say at this point they don't.

Comment: See? the better the requirement definition, the better the solution... so not much to do, link each record with its fingerprint either in the same table or a related table.